# Sync scrollbar div to non-scrolled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, scroll

I have a web page with three divs that are synced together.

```
    +----------+
    |   TOP    |
+---+----------+
|   |         ||
| L | CENTER  ||
|   |_________||
+---+----------+

<!--Rough HTML-->
<div>
  <div class="topbar-wrapper">
    <div class="topbar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center-wrapper"> <!-- Set to the window size & overflow:scroll -->
      <div class="center"></div> <!-- Has the content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The center div has scroll bars, both horizontal and vertical. The top and left divs do not have scroll bars. Instead, when the horizontal scroll bar is moved, the scroll event updates the top div's `margin-left` appropriately. Likewise when the vertical scroll bar is moved, the `margin-top` is updated. In both cases, they are set to a negative value.

```
$('.center-wrapper').scroll(function(e) {
  $('.sidebar').css({marginTop: -1 * $(this).scrollTop()});
  $('.topbar').css({marginLeft: -1 * $(this).scrollLeft()});
});
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in Safari, there is a delay between moving the scroll bar and the negative margin being properly set.

Is there a better way to do this? Or is there some way to get rid of the lag in Safari?

EDIT:

Check out this Fiddle to see the lag in Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/qh2K3/

Comment: It's a calendar app where you have dates across the top and people down the left. Each row corresponds to a person and each column to a date, so I want them to stay synced up, but I don't want to scroll the dates or people off the screen.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Can't replicate with this fiddle in Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/MQr6J/1/.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information? Which version of Safari (desktop, mobile, number) are you seeing this in? Is there by any chance another script that works with scroll events and the scroll position on the relevant elements?

Comment: Safari on OS X. It "works", but there is a lag between the divs scrolling. That's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Caching the 'wrappers' may help (not recreate a new jquery object each time by using `$(this)` ) **http://jsfiddle.net/gBDL8/3** - likely not the fix but won't harm it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me know if [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmpRa/) works better.  I experienced the same "lag" on my end too (Safari 7 on OS X) and these small CSS changes *significantly* improved it.  My best guess is that Safari is being lazy and has not turned on its high-performance motors.  We can force Safari to turn it on using some simple CSS:

```
.topbar-wrapper, .sidebar-wrapper, .center-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

This enables [hardware accelerated CSS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) in Safari by offloading some of the work to the GPU.  It improves rendering in the browser, which may have been the issue in the delay.

Comment: Good find. This has no lag for me in Safari 7.0.1. Adding this CSS code to the fiddle of Zword removes lag there as well. Interestingly, subpixel  font-rendering is preserved. I think it used to be that turning on hardware acceleration disabled subpixel rendering.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue a few times, where safari seems to be lagging when incrementally moving elements based on events like this.

Here's how I've solved the problem in the past.

In browsers that support hardware acceleration, using any "3d" CSS property will enable the hardware acc.

If 3D transforms is supported, we might as well use translate3d to move the elements, as that makes for smoother movements than shifting pixels.

This means we first have to figure out the right prefix for the CSS transform property, then check support for 3D transforms. If we have support, translate the elements, if not shift pixels.

By figuring out the prefixes and 3D support without libraries it should be just about as fast as it can get, and has no dependencies.

```
var parent     = document.querySelector('.center-wrapper'),
    sidebar    = document.querySelector('.sidebar'),
    topbar     = document.querySelector('.topbar'),
    has3D      = false,
    transform  = null,
    transforms = {
            'webkitTransform' : '-webkit-transform',
            'OTransform'      : '-o-transform',
            'msTransform'     : '-ms-transform',
            'MozTransform'    : '-moz-transform',
            'transform'       : 'transform'
    };

for (var k in transforms) if (k in parent.style) transform = k;

if ( transform !== null ) {
    sidebar.style[transform] = 'translate3d(0,0,0)'; // start hardware acc
    topbar.style[transform]  = 'translate3d(0,0,0)'; // start hardware acc
    // check support
    var s = window.getComputedStyle(sidebar).getPropertyValue(transforms[transform]);
    has3D = s !== undefined && s.length > 0 && s !== "none";
}

if (has3D) {
    parent.onscroll = function (e) {
        sidebar.style[transform] = 'translate3d(0px, '+ (this.scrollTop * -1) +'px, 0px)';
        topbar.style[transform]  = 'translate3d('+ (this.scrollLeft * -1) +'px, 0px, 0px)';
    }
}else{
    parent.onscroll = function (e) {
        sidebar.style.marginTop = (this.scrollTop  * -1) + 'px';
        topbar.style.marginLeft = (this.scrollLeft * -1) + 'px';
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qh2K3/7/)

Remember to put this after the elements in the DOM, as in right before `</body>`, or if that's not possible, it has to be wrapped in a DOM ready handler.

As a sidenote, querySelector is not supported in IE7 and below, if that's an issue you have to polyfill it.

Answer (score 2):

## Caching selectors will help.

**Changing :**

```
$('.center-wrapper').scroll(function(e) {
  $('.sidebar').css({marginTop: -1 * $(this).scrollTop()});
  $('.topbar').css({marginLeft: -1 * $(this).scrollLeft()});
});
```

**To :**

```
var _scroller = $('.center-wrapper'),
    _swrapper = $('.sidebar-wrapper'),
    _twrapper = $('.topbar-wrapper');

_scroller.scroll(function (e) {
    _swrapper.scrollTop(_scroller.scrollTop());
    _twrapper.scrollLeft(_scroller.scrollLeft());
});
```

**`.scroll()` will be working very hard if it has to recreate jquery objects `$(this)` each time.**

*Wrote this in a comment last night, and while not been able to test yet, actually felt today that this is should be added as directly relates to performance.*

We can try it out - **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/gBDL8/3/)**

---

## More / The Methods - making them native too

There are also another jquery method calls we can cut out too. `.scrollTop()` and `.scrollLeft()` by caching and returning the native `_scrollernative = _scroller.get(0)` to make use of the readily available properties `scrollLeft`.

**Like :**

```
var _scroller = $('.center-wrapper'),
    _scrollernative = _scroller.get(0),
    _swrapper = $('.sidebar-wrapper').get(0),
    _twrapper = $('.topbar-wrapper').get(0);

_scroller.scroll(function (e) {
    _swrapper.scrollTop = _scrollernative.scrollTop;
    _twrapper.scrollLeft = _scrollernative.scrollLeft;
});
```

We can try this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7h36T/1/)**

---

---

I appreciate that your code might be looking at more than one of these controls on the page, and that's why you have used classes and needing to find `S(this)` instead of using ID's.

For that I would still use the above caching methods but before that we need to create them one by one. ( caching before we initialise the scroll() function per instance )

```
(function() {
    var _scroller = $('.center-wrapper'),
    _swrapper = $('.sidebar-wrapper').get(0),
    _twrapper = $('.topbar-wrapper').get(0);

    function setScrollers(_thisscroller) {
        _scrollernative = _thisscroller.get(0);
        /* start the scroll listener per this event */
        _thisscroller.scroll(function (e) {
            _swrapper.scrollTop = _scrollernative.scrollTop;
            _twrapper.scrollLeft = _scrollernative.scrollLeft;
        }); 
    }

    _scroller.each(function() { setScrollers($(this)); });

})();
```

We can try this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UBh94/)**

---

But As I see that .sidebar-wrapper and .topbar-wrapper are unique, mabye .center-wrapper is unique too.

So how about finally using id's for these elements to shorten everything up.

```
var _scroller = document.getElementById('center-wrapper'),
    _swrapper = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper'),
    _twrapper = document.getElementById('topbar-wrapper');

    _scroller.onscroll = function() {
      _swrapper.scrollTop = _scroller.scrollTop;
      _twrapper.scrollLeft = _scroller.scrollLeft;
    };
```

We can try this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vLeDB/1/)**

---

Comment: Doing this and adding in the neat CSS that @Irvin Zhan has given should make this pretty efficient - **http://jsfiddle.net/v9vBg/1/**

Comment: no suck eggs intended as I know tghw gets this off the first title. ( I was on just a roll typing ) *These examples are based on the code in the demo ( http://jsfiddle.net/qh2K3 ) provided.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `marginTop & marginLeft` to change margins of `.sidebar & .topbar` use `scrollTop & scrollLeft` for the overflowing divs `.sidebar-wrapper & .topbar-wrapper` and see if it now works in **Safari**:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VLwW/)

```
$('.center-wrapper').scroll(function(e) {
   $('.sidebar-wrapper').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
   $('.topbar-wrapper').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

---

### [Try this fiddle made to ***look best*** in safari and ***tested***](http://jsfiddle.net/2VLwW/2/)

Comment: While this works in Safari, there is a lag between the two divs, which is exactly the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: @tghw can you clarify what do you mean by lag becoz at my side I am getting correct output

Comment: Since I am getting correct output using my fiddle according to what I have understood from the question asked @tghw to better know about what you have tried using my code can you post an updated fiddle?

Comment: Indeed, I am also experiencing this "lag" on Safari (OS X)

Comment: @IrvinZhan yesterday I downloaded Safari 5.1.7 and tested in it and it is giving me correct ouput without lag

Comment: Interesting -- I'm running Safari 7.  Maybe a bug or a recent change in that version?